# Specify value to appear last in ordered results

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to specify the last value to order Mysql results by. Eg if I have the following table

```
id    |   Colour
 1    |   Blue
 2    |   Red
 3    |   Yellow
 4    |   Green
```

Could I have the results of my query display 'Red' last

```
SELECT * 
FROM colours 
ORDER By colours ASC [but show Red last]
```

Comment: Add a `rank` column to your colour table, populate it with integers, and then order on colours.rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some conditional logic in your `ORDER BY`.  This will sort the data in the specific order that you want, `Red` always being last:

```
SELECT id, colour
FROM colours
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN colour <> 'Red' 
    THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, colour;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f21/3). This uses a `CASE` expression to assign a value to each row that is used for the ordering.  `Red` is assigned a higher value, so it will appear a the end of the list.

This could also be written testing for the Colour being equal to `Red` first:

```
SELECT id, colour
FROM colours
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN colour = 'Red' 
    THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, colour;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f21/2). Both versions will return:

```
| ID | COLOUR |
|----|--------|
|  1 |   Blue |
|  4 |  Green |
|  5 | Orange |
|  6 |   Teal |
|  3 | Yellow |
|  2 |    Red |
```

Comment: You might argue that it reads a little more straightforward to test for equality then setting the sort value to a higher number. Obviously it makes no difference int the end though.

Comment: @shawnt00 Correct, just to make it obvious that it works either way, I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Some people get worked up about that stuff. I'm not generally one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There might be cases where you'd need to do this with a single-column sort. And some queries/platforms require the sorting column to be part of the output.

```
SELECT
    id, colour,
    case when colour = 'Red' then 'zzzzz' else '' end + colour as colour_sort
FROM colours 
ORDER By colour_sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a work around, but will get what you want

```
(SELECT * FROM colours WHERE Colour != 'Red' ORDER By Colour ASC)
UNION SELECT * FROM colours WHERE Colour = 'Red'
```

Comment: The order by generally applies to the entire union. Not sure if that works on some platforms though.

Comment: MySQL supports this, but most others don't.

Comment: It's a valid solution. While it does have downsides, it doesn't require a case expression either. This might even be the best solution for a weird platform out there.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a case statement to map your colours:

```
select id, colour,
case 
   when colour = 'Red' then 1
   when colour = 'blue' then 2
   when colour = 'Yellow' then 3
   when colour = 'Green' then 4
   end as SortOrder
from colours 
ORDER By SortOrder
```

Comment: You'd think it would make sense to handle them all. Maybe the downvote was because you reversed the ordering?

Comment: Not sure.  It was a surprise to me!  I figure that way you can guarantee the order, say if it's for a bar graph or something where the actual visual order of the colours is important.

Comment: Actually OP did want sorting alphabetical by color name. So yours has the others out of order as well. I can't guess why though.